# MS Word VBA: How to replace each word with its translation while keeping formatting

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a word document and want to replace each single word with its translation while keeping all the formatting intact. I cannot use "Find And Replace" dialog because I am not trying replace a particular set of words but I am replacing all the words. How do I do that using VBA?

**Update**
I am using Word 2010. So far, I can loop through the words using ActiveDocument.Range.Words property but I don't know how to replace those words with its translation? While replacing, I want to keep all the formattings like font name, size, color, background color, underline, bold in short all the formatting options as it is.

Comment: You need to provide more details in order to get any useful answers, please see [the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). What version of Word are you using? What have you tried so far? Any code samples? Etc.

Comment: If you loop through ActiveDocument.Range.Words you can replace the words one at a time; note however that if you do so, each word will take on the formatting of the *first character* of the word. If the word has varied formatting within it (e.g. the last letter of the word is underlined), then that formatting will be lost.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have an array of words `("apple", "book", "cat")` and the array of their translation `("pomme", "livre", "chat")`.

Your goal is to bulk change words one by one.

So you need a loop. Here is the loop that may help (if I understand your problem correctly).

**Bulk change upon two arrays**:

```
Option Explicit
Sub replaceArrayForArray()
'
'to create array use prefix\suffix and replacing tool http://textmechanic.com/
'
'
findArray = Array("apple", "book", "cat")
replArray = Array("pomme", "livre", "chat")

For i = 0 To UBound(findArray)
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = findArray(i)
        .Replacement.Text = replArray(i)
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = True
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute replace:=wdReplaceAll
Next i
End Sub
```

The more diffucult issue could have been if you worked with **figures** and you had to **bulk change figures without overlap**. The method with the use of the same  macro more or less described here: **[MS Word Macro to increment all numbers in word document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30154503/ms-word-macro-to-increment-all-numbers-in-word-document/35542069#35542069)**.