# MS Word Macro to increment all numbers in word document

Tags: vba, macos, ms-word

I am trying to make a MS-word Macro to increment all numbers in the word document which are within brackets,   eg original numbers [1] [2] [3]  [4] , after incrementing all numbers by 10, above numbers will be changed to [11] [12] [13] [14]

I'm stuck in the code below and not familiar with VBA before. Can anyone suggest, what to add in code below to perform above macro??

```
Sub IncrementNumbers()
'
' IncrementNumbers Macro
'
'

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim RngStory As Range, StrStart As String, StrEnd As String
StrStart = "["
StrEnd = "]"
Set RngStory = ActiveDocument.Range
With RngStory.Find
```

**Some code here to increment and replace numbers**

```
Set RngStory = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

There is another option. I hope you are familiar with the concept of arrays (in any language). Just keep in mind that in VBA arrays are inside brackets `("[1]", "[2]")`. If not, it won't be a problem.

If your goal is to replace `[1]` for `[11]`, `[2]` for `[12]`, ... `[n]` for `[n+10]` then you may do the following.

**Please, consider to look here. The answers are alike. [Changing numbering in word using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29965120/changing-numbering-in-word-using-vba/35541096#35541096)**

The concept is to work with two arrays two times: I) replace `[1]` for `@@@[1]@@@`, `[2]` for `@@@[2]@@@`, ..., `[n]` for `@@@[n]@@@`; II) replace `@@@[1]@@@` for `[11]`, `@@@[2]@@@` for `[12]`, ..., `@@@[n]@@@` for `[n+10]`.

More profound view:

1.1) Create searchArray from [1] to [n]. You can use this. http://textmechanic.com/generate-list-numbers/. Prefix numbers with: "`[`", suffix with: "`]`", Join with: "`,`".

1.2) With the same tool create replaceArray with prefix "`@@@`" and sufix "`@@@`" (for uniqueness), i.e. `@@@[1]@@@`, `@@@[2]@@@`, .. `@@@[n]@@@`.

1.3) Replace searchArray for replaceArray.

**[Adapt code from Annex]**.

2.1) Create searchArray, it is the same as in 1.2)

2.2) With the tool http://textmechanic.com/generate-list-numbers/ create replaceArray from [10] to [n+10]. I.e. `[10]`, `[11]`, ... `[n]`

2.3) Replace searchArray for replaceArray.

**[Adapt code from Annex]**.

**Annex**

```
Option Explicit
Sub replaceArrayForArray()
'
'to create array use prefix\suffix and replacing tool http://textmechanic.com/
'
'
findArray = Array("[1]", "[2]", "[3]")
replArray = Array("@@@[1]@@@", "@@@[2]@@@", "@@@[3]@@@")

For i = 0 To UBound(findArray)
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = findArray(i)
        .Replacement.Text = replArray(i)
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = True
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute replace:=wdReplaceAll
Next i
End Sub
```

**PS:** Why not replace `[1]` for `[11]`? But we have to firstly replace `[1]` for `@[1]@` and then secondly `@[1]@` for `[11]`?

Because in 10 iterations through loop we will have two `[11]` that will both turn into `[21]`; then three `[21]` that will turn into `[31]` etc.

**PPS:** Both parts of the code if you'd like to copy and paste the answer: **http://codepad.org/sZEG78ak**. But still you will have to expand arrays as noted above.